# fs.writeFileSync to fs.writeFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am wondering, how to change  `fs.writeFileSync` to `fs.writeFile`

```
var users = {
  "(there is users id)": {
    "bal": 28,
    "lastclaim": 1612012406047,
    "lastwork": 1612013463181,
    "workers": 1,
    "rebirths": 1
  }
}
setInterval(function(){
   users = Object.entries(users).reduce((init, [key, value] )=> ({...init, [key]: {...value, bal: value.bal += 1 }}),{})
   fs.writeFileSync("./DB/users.json", JSON.stringify(users));
},1000)
```

I am using this code, to make users get a certain value of money every 1 second. I want to change the `fs.writeFileSync("./DB/users.json", JSON.stringify(users));` to a `fs.writeFile()`, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried to [read the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Yes, I did read the documentation, but i didn't understand it too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```js
var users = {
  "(there is users id)": {
    "bal": 28,
    "lastclaim": 1612012406047,
    "lastwork": 1612013463181,
    "workers": 1,
    "rebirths": 1
  }
}
setInterval(function(){
   users = Object.entries(users).reduce((init, [key, value] )=> ({...init, [key]: {...value, bal: value.bal += 1 }}),{})
   fs.writeFile("./DB/users.json", JSON.stringify(users), () => {});
},1000)
```

but I don't see the point?

Comment: Don't forget that it's unsafe to use `fs.writeFile()` multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback.